# Which one is the right question "You liked it?" or "Did you like it?"

Tags: questions

Which one is the right question "You liked it?" or "Did you like it?"

For me both look right, but I am not sure.

Comment: Whether or not something is right, depends entirely on the context.

Comment: _Did you like it?_ is in the standard form of a question. _You liked it_ is a statement, but a simple sentence like this can be made into a question by adding a question mark or, in speech, by the tone of voice used.

Comment: The _declarative question_  (well covered on ELU, and by Nordquist at 'ThoughtCo') is more informal, and though not ungrammatical, might be considered inappropriate in formal contexts.

Comment: It's worth noting that You liked it?" is not an alternative to "Did you like it?".  "You liked it?" and similar constructions are often a question that expresses surprise -> "You liked it? I thought it was horrible!" and it would be wrong to ask "This answer is correct?"

Answer (score 1):

You can use both the sentences.
But the sentence (did you like it?) is appropriate grammatically.
You can use the second one sentence in informal usage
and you tone/accent should be like that you are asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to write correct formal grammar you should write:

> Did you like it?

That is a formally correct grammatical question.

In informal speech and writing

> You liked it?

Is used frequently enough to be acceptable, and those who hold that usage defines grammar would consider it correct.